# How to mark constexpr arrays as allowing overlap in memory

Tags: c++

I have a tool function like this

```cpp
template<class T>
constexpr inline bool is_all_byte_zero(T&&a){
    constexpr byte all_byte_zero_v[sizeof(T)]={};
    return equal(cast_to_data(addressof(a)),all_byte_zero_v,sizeof(T));
}
```

What I want to know is, is there any way (preferably a generic standard way) to mark `all_byte_zero_v` so that the compiler knows that I don't care if different `all_byte_zero_v<T>` overlap in memory so that it's easier for the compiler to optimize, or does the compiler do these optimizations automatically and I'm just worrying about nothing?

Comment: Your main problem is not compiler optimizations, but undefined behavior.

Comment: `inline` is implied by `constexpr`. If you actually call the function at compile time it will complain about the cast and flag the UB. And it's probably faster to just test each against 0 rather than against an array of 0.